# How can i fit my webPage in browser when user makes browser window big?

Tags: html, css

In facebook when user makes browser size big, facebook's blue top bar adjusts itself and keeps its contents in middle. I want to apply this thing in my webPage as well. Anyone has any idea how to do that using CSS and HTML. I am quite new in this. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: take a look at http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/css-layouts/ (Not my site)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a block element such as a `div` will be as wide as possible by default. Give that a background color, use CSS to set `text-align:center` or give a child element a fixed width and a `margin:0 auto` to center it within the edge to edge block element.

See example here: http://jsbin.com/ufemim

Answer (score 1):

For this to work you must

- have fixed width defined for that dive
- {margin:auto} defined for that div

You can use background-colo, and border CSS properties while you are fixing the positioning. This is pretty standard way of doing it in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Html:

```
<div id="header">My header</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width:800px;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:blue;
}
```

You would have to do this for any other div's you would like centered as well.